# geometric series and generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

For $x > 1$, the geometric series $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n{x}^i$ is equal to $\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$.

By getting the limit,

$$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n{x}^i = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}
$$

$$
= \infty
$$

However, the generating function $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0}x^n$ is equal to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ since

$$
\sum\limits_{n \geq 0}{x}^n - x\sum\limits_{n \geq 0}{x}^n= (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots) - (x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots) = 1
$$

$$
\Rightarrow (1-x)\sum\limits_{n \geq 0}{x}^n= 1
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n \geq 0}{x}^n= \frac{1}{1-x}
$$

Obviously, $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a finite number.

What is the underlying concept that makes them yield different results?

Comment: A "generating function" need not be a function in the usual sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this is not the intended interpretation, one could also make sense of the identity
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n = (1-x)^{-1} \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
*formally*; i.e., in the ring of formal power series $\mathbf C[[x]]$. The user Bill Dubuque explains the idea in several posts in this site; see, e.g., his answer to the post [Product of two power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29549).

The advantage in interpreting $(\dagger)$ formally is that since $x$ is an *indeterminate* rather than a number, there are no longer any convergence issues. In this sense, the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$ is the **same as the finite *thing*** $(1-x)^{-1}$.

The flip side of this is that one can no longer plug in values into the series: it does not make sense to talk about the sum of the series at $x = \frac{1}{2}$. Thus the statement "the series converges for $|x| < 1$ and diverges otherwise" is meaningless under this interpretation.

Comment: (I am fully aware that there is a chance the OP may not understand the answer. This post is meant for all readers, not just the OP.)

Answer (score 2):

They're not different. The generating function is only defined for when $|x| < 1$. Similarly, the geometric series only converges for $|x| < 1$. And in that case, $\lim x^n = 0$ and you see that the two expressions are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The given derivation of the fact that $\sum_{ n \geq 0 } x^n = \frac{ 1 }{ 1 - x }$, doesn't address convergence of the intermediate series at all.  You can't ignore this issue in a derivation and then hope to plug in numbers to the result.

The derivation given shows that the given identity is valid in the context of [formal power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series), which are important in the study of generating functions.

As @mixedmath correctly states, you may only substitute numbers into this identity if $| x | < 1$.