# Multiplying and factoring in Formal Power Series

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

I'm working with some formal power series in my homework. Somewhere in the middle of my hw problem I reach a point where I would really like to factor, but I'm not sure if I can.

Suppose $F_k$ converges to F in K[[x]].
Is $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} F_k  - x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} F_k$
$ =  (1- x) \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} F_k$? I was told to be careful when dealing with formal infinite products, but I feel like that warning was more for multiplying infinite products together.

1) Can I do this simplification? $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} F_k  - x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} F_k =  (1- x) \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} F_k$?

2) If so, how do I justify that I am allowed to do so?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29549/242) for the appropriate notion of *convergence*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object $K[[x]]$ is often known as the *ring of formal power series* over a field $K$, and not for nothing — it is a ring (indeed, a commutative ring). The ring axioms imply the identity $a-ba = (1-b)a$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!