# Prove that if B(0) = 0, then A(B(x)) is a formal power series

Tags: combinatorics, function-and-relation-composition, formal-power-series

I'm working through my Combinatorics textbook and am stuck on this proof. The textbook explains it pretty well, but I am having trouble with one of the steps. I was hoping I could get some help here

Theorem: If A(x) and B(x) are formal power series and the constant term of B(x) is zero, then A(B(x)) is a formal power series.

Proof:

Let $A(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ....$ and $B(x) = xC(x)$
*This is so that B(x) has no constant term*

$$A(B(x)) = A(xC(x))$$
$$= a_0 + a_1xC(x) + a_2x^2(C(x))^2 + ...$$

For each $k \gt 0$, $a_kx^kC(x)^k$ is a formal power series since it is the product of formal power series. Also, for each $m \lt k$, $[x^m](a_kx^kC(x))^k = 0$. *This is because when $x^k$ is distributed into $C(x)^k$, the smallest degree of x will be k, so all coefficients of powers of x less than k will be 0. This next part is where I'm lost*

Therefore
$$[x^n]A(B(x)) = [x^n](a_0 + a_1xC(x) + a_2x^2C(x)^2 + ...)$$
$$= [x^n](a_0 + a_1xC(x) + a_2x^2C(x)^2 + ... + a_nx^nC(x)^n)$$

*I don't understand how we could have gone from the first line to the second. Could someone please be kind enough to explain this to me? I have a feeling it's simple, but for some reason I just can't see it.*

Thanks

Comment: Every power of $x$ appearing in $a_kx^kC(x)^k$ is at least $k$ (because of the factor of $x^k$). If $n<k$, then $x^n$ does not appear in this term (or, if you prefer, appears with coefficient $0$). Thus, the only terms that contribute to the $x^n$ term of $A(B(x))$ are those with $k\le n$.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was simple. I just couldn't see it.

Comment: @The_Questioner See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/29549/242) for a natural notion of convergence for such formal power series that makes clear this and related matters.