# Condition for convergence of series of formal power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, formal-power-series

Proposition 1.1.8 in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29549), from "Enumerative Combinatorics" by Stanley, says

> The infinite series $\sum_j F_j(x)$ converges if and only if $\lim_{j \to \infty} \deg(F_j(x)) = \infty$.

where each $F_j(x)$ is a formal power series.

I must be misunderstanding something fundamental because this makes no sense to me. Consider the sequence of formal power series defined as $F_j(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$ for all $j$. Then the series "converges" to $\infty + \infty x + \infty x^2 + \cdots$, which means that it doesn't converge, but it still satisfies the condition $\lim_{j \to \infty} \deg(F_j(x)) = \infty$... right?

Comment: Here, the degree of a formal series refers to the minimum exponent with non-zero coefficient, not the maximum one.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh.. that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: Essentially, this is equivalent to the requirement that each degree appear in only finitely many of the $F_j(x)$'s so that the coefficient at each $x^n$ in $\sum_j F_j(x)$ is only a finite sum.